# Obj-C: Replacing two substrings with NSDictionary objects -- only one is changing

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

Have an interesting problem. I have an NSDictionary, such as:

```
self.abbreviations = @{
                        @"REGL"     :   @"REGIONAL",
                        @"REG"      :   @"REGIONAL",
                        @"RE"       :   @"REGIONAL",
                        @"CO"       :   @"COUNTY",
}
```

If the abbreviation is noted in a string, I want to replace it with the full name by using:

```
if ([destination containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@,",key]])
        {
            destinationRev = [[destination stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@" "]mutableCopy];
        }

for (id key in self.abbreviations)
{
    if ([destinationRev containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", key]])
    {
        destination = [destinationRev stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:key
                                                                withString:[self.abbreviations objectForKey:key]];
    }
}
```

However for the name: CITY CO REGL, I have the following output: CITY CO REGIONAL. I.e., CO is not changing although it is between two spaces.

What am I missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign the result of a single replacement to a reference `destination`, leave the `destinationRev` untouched and overwrite `destination` in every single loop run. Therefore you will only get a string with the last replacement.

```
for (id key in self.abbreviations)
{
  if ([destinationRev containsString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ", key]])
  {
    /* ---> */ destinationRev = [destinationRev stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:key
                                                            withString:[self.abbreviations objectForKey:key]];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Amin! The only change I made was adding mutableCopy at the end to avoid incompatible pointer type error. Cheers!

Comment: Well, you did not post the declaration of the reference variables. However, I do not see, why you need a mutable string at all. `-stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` works on immutable strings and returns an immutable string, because it creates a new instance every time. Maybe you should use `-replaceOccurrencesOfString:withString:options:range:` (`NSMutableString`) instead.